# Android fragments and creating new instances of them. Do you always need a container?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Fragments is something that I am still trying to understand, I get some of it but not all of it.

My question is, do i need a container to start a new fragment instance? 
This is what I have been currently doing to launch a fragment from my current activity that i have a container in.

```
    FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(container.getId(), new OtherFragment());
    ft.commit();
```

So my main activity has a container where I can switch from 4 fragments. Now lets say I click on one of the list items in my 3rd tab. That launches a new activity that shows another listview. Then if i click on the item on that listview, i launch a new activity. Then, were it says "tap for more information", I will be launching a new activity (I haven't created this yet, and that is why I am asking this).

But I feel like it could just be launching fragments instead of activities. If so, how do I go about doing that, because I feel like I need some type of container to put it in since I have tried launching a newinstance of a dummy fragment class i created it but it doesn't launch. If not, how do i just create a new instance of it without a container, if possible.

Or do I only use fragments whenever they will be similar and will have a container to be put in??

And I could do fragmentActivity, but that is almost the same as Activity. The reason I ask is because we shouldn't have so many activities, right? or does having as many as activities as you want not affect the project performance? Because right now I usually create activities for everything, unless its like the first picture where I will have something similar that can be put into a container.

Thanks.

[image]   [image]   [image]

Answer (score 0):

You're going to to pretty much the same thing that you did to show the first fragment.

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
if (mDetailFragment == null)
{
    mDetailFragment = new DetailFragment();
}
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(container.getId(), mDetailFragment);
ft.commit();
```

You're going to want to keep references to your fragments so you're not creating them new every time. To improve the user experience you can add animations to the transition and, if it makes sense, add the fragment to the backstack.

```
ft.addToBackstack("OtherFragment");
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit, R.anim.popEnter, R.anim.popExit);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. So would you say that launching or creating too many activities can affect the app performance? I'm fairly new to android so I am wanting to make sure that I learn the correct ways. So like for this project, I feel like I could be creating fragments for some of my other classes siince all I am doing is displaying info or text. @CaseyB

Comment: Android is really good about killing things that are no longer in use so it shouldn't be too much of a problem but if you can keep it around you might as well.

Comment: I'm kind of confused on your answer. If I'm understanding correctly, you are putting mDetailFragment into a container. But if I put it into the container as the first outages tab, with the listview. Then the tabbar will stay on top. The way i set up my main is that I have the tab bar locked on top and am only changing what goes under it with whatever of the 4 fragments I need. So this woulnd't work, right?

Comment: Your activity layout should be just the container. Then you can put your tab bar fragment in there. When you move to a different fragment replace your tab bar fragment with the new one.

Comment: Yeah I thought about that. But is there an advantage of just doing everything with fragments or activities? Because I feel like you could do either implement a lot of activities or a lot of fragments. So is there an upside/downside to either? Since you mentioned that using a lot of activies isn't a big problem with android.Thanks! @CaseyB

Comment: The only downside to using Activities instead of Fragments is that you lose flexibility. With Fragments you can have many fragments all laid out nicely on the same screen. With an Activity you get just that Activity. So if you want to move stuff around or support a tablet or something it's easier with Fragments.